# Activating 'on click' event on the path created by router in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geocoding, open-source-routing-machine

I have some points retrieved from the database, and with them, I draw and create my path and markers.

I would like that when the user adds another marker to the route, a `click` event is activated.

I need this to update some information that will be passed visually to users.

An example is if we look at the image below. I have 22 bookmarks. If the user adds a marker, I will have 23, and I would like the first and last markers to have different colors.

With the `map.on('click')` event, I can, but I want it to be on the path.

[image]

Follow my code below:

```
    var routingMarkersPaneIda = map.createPane('routingMarkersIda');
    routingMarkersPaneIda.style.zIndex = 600;
    var routingMarkersShadowPaneIda = map.createPane('routingMarkersShadowIda');
    routingMarkersShadowPaneIda.style.zIndex = 500;
    var defaultLineOptionsIda = {
        styles: [{color: "blue", opacity: 1}],
    };

    for (let index = 0; index < ida.length; index++) {
        way_ida.push(new L.latLng(ida[index].latitude, ida[index].longitude));
    }

     var r_ida = L.Routing.control({
        show: true,
        geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
        autoRoute: true,
        waypoints: way_ida,
        routeWhileDragging: true,
        collapsible: true,
        lineOptions: defaultLineOptionsIda,
        router: new L.Routing.osrmv1({
            serviceUrl: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:5000/route/v1',
        }),
        createMarker: function (i, wp, nWps) {
            var marker = L.marker(wp.latLng, {
                pane: 'routingMarkersIda',
                shadowPane: 'routingMarkersShadowIda',
                draggable: true,
                icon: criandoNumeracao(i, way_ida)
            });
            return marker;
        }
    }).addTo(map);

function criandoNumeracao(i, pontos){

        quantidade_pontos = pontos.length

        if ((i == 0) || (i == quantidade_pontos-1)){
            markerColor = 'red'
        } else {
            markerColor = 'cyan'
        }

        var colorMarker = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
            svg : false,
            icon: 'fa-number',
            markerColor: markerColor,
            shape: 'circle',
            prefix: 'fa',
            number: i+1 
        });

        return colorMarker
    }
```

I would like it to be possible to add another point exactly in the existing routing path. And to make it clear, this path is result of routing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Question is too broad, it has many "ands". Please limit is to a single question.

Comment: Thank you for the tips @TomazicM.

Comment: You don't mention that in the question, but code indicates that this path is result of routing. You want to add another point exactly on the existing routing path? Or you want route to be changed so that it goes through new point? Please edit your question and clarify this.

Comment: It's done, sorry for anything @TomazicM